# I can not separate the HTTP body header

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to detect your inside a string comes the header of the http request or not, for this I am detecting when two line breaks (according to standard):

```
String bufferRequest = socketServer.getBufferPart();

Pattern regexHTTP = Pattern.compile("((.+\\n)+\\n)");
Matcher regexMatcherHTTP = regexHTTP.matcher(bufferRequest);

if (regexMatcherHTTP.find()) {
    String requestHeader = regexMatcherHTTP.group(1);
    // ...
```

The request buffer example:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
abc: def
ghi: jkl

body part 1 ...

body part 2 ...

body etc ...
```

Need get from "GET / " to "jkl", but he does not detect me, what did I do wrong?.

In regexr.com works fine: http://regexr.com/3ekjm

Comment: Could you not read each line until you get the first empty one?

Comment: I would have to do a for each line, if the user sends many header lines the cpu process could be higher than using the regular expression, otherwise it is less elegant hahaha.

Comment: it's fallacious to think that reading many header lines in a for loop leads to higher CPU usage. if anything, Regex parsing could be slightly costlier, but in case, you shouldn't worry about performance unless and until you notice a bottleneck which you detect by [profiling](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/profiler.html).

Comment: Things do not happen until they happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution:

```
Pattern regexHTTP = Pattern.compile("((.+(\\r\\n|\\n))+(\\r\\n|\\n))");
```

Comment: your requirements changes , good you figured it out ,+1 ,keep it up

Answer (score 0):

I think you need use DOTALL flag, as well I modified regex a bit.

Try this:

```
Pattern regexHTTP = Pattern.compile("((.+?)([\\r]?\\n){2}).*", Pattern.DOTALL);
```

I used '([\\r]?\\n)' because in Linux/Unix line ending is just '\n', while in Windows it is '\r\n'. So I am not clear what you will have in real messages.